# How can i count the failure rate of in-app purchase in iOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Recently i was told to count the failure rate of my app's(An Objective-C App) in-app purchase.

Is there any tool or any open-source lib that i can use?
Do u have any idea?

Answer (score 3):

You should use your analytics tool to do that (Firebase, Amplitude, your custom tool…). To compute that ratio you will need to track 2 events `failure` and `success` to get that ratio.

To do that you will need to track the failures in your [`SKPaymentTransactionObserver`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymenttransactionobserver/1506107-paymentqueue?language=objc).
Failures can be identified by checking the `transactionState`.
You should be tracking both [`SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymenttransactionstate/skpaymenttransactionstatefailed?language=objc) and [`SKPaymentTransactionStateDeferred`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymenttransactionstate/skpaymenttransactionstatedeferred?language=objc).
The deferred state occurs when your user needs the parental authorisation to purchase.
You should also track the error code and message as your event properties to be able to categorised your errors.

I attached an example of the fail rate on an application computed by [Purchasely](https://www.purchasely.com)
[image: Example of a fail rate]

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep track of any transactions coming back on the `SKPaymentTransactionObserver protocol` method

`- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray<SKPaymentTransaction *> *)transactions`

1. Keep track of the total number of transactions that have state `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing`
2. Keep track of the total number of transactions that have state `SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed`

Keep in mind that if the user cancels the payment sheet you'll get a failed transaction back, so you might want to examine the user info on that `transaction.error` to determine if that failed transaction is of interest or not.

Another thing is that if parental controls are enabled, the transactions will come back as `SKPaymentTransactionStateDeferred` and if no action is taken from the owner, they will silently fail without any information coming back at the delegate method.

I'd suggest sending those events on your backend or analytics tool and make the comparison logic there